# I want to read a file from a directory folder

Tags: perl

How can i read a file from a folder?

ive tried

```
open(my $yourhandle, '<', 'spool.txt') 
    or die "Unable to open file, $!";
close($yourhandle);
```

But that code only opens the file, dont read it :/

Comment: Type 'how to read a file in perl' into a search engine?

Comment: This is covered in the perl introduction: [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Files-and-I%2fO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the diamond operator to read from an opened file handle:

```
open my $FH, '<', '/path/to/spool.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$FH>) {
    print "I've read: $line";
}
close $FH;
```

Comment: See also the perl doc [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Files-and-I%2fO)